# Formatting issue with the body of the e-mail with PHPMailer

Tags: php, phpmailer, contact-form

I'm using PHPMailer for the contact form on my website.
It works fine but the only issue is that everything is put on the same row in the body of the message (the message, the url the message is sent from, and the user agent), despite the "\n" which should put everything on a different line.
What is the issue?
Thanks,

```
$mail->Body =  $_POST['message']."\nFrom page: ". str_replace("http://", "", $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) . "\n" . $_SERVER ['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
```

Comment: I think the display will depend on your email client, try using "\r\n" instead of just "\n" and see if that changes?

Comment: Thanks, using <br> solved the issue!

Comment: You could just set `$mail->isHTML(false)` and it will send as plain text, in which white space and line breaks are significant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows uses `\r\n` Carriage Return, Line Feed (from typewriter days) and 'nix operating systems use Line Feed `\n` so it is likely you were testing in a windows environment. In any case the default output is in HTML so you would indeed want to use `<br>` instead. Not sure about PHPMailer's `altBody` though, maybe you can find out.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have enabled HTML email, for instance like this:

```
$mail->IsHTML(true);
```

The solution is then to replace "\n" with "<br>", like so:

```
$mail->Body =  $_POST['message'].<br>From page: ". str_replace("http://", "", $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) . "<br>" . $_SERVER ['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
```